# DotCover fails unit test that pass in Resharper

Tags: unit-testing, resharper, dotcover

Hi fellow programmers!

I'm trying to do some test coverage using DotCover 2.7 combined with Resharper 7.1.3. I have approximately 1300 tests in four different test projects in my solution, all of which pass when run with resharper. However, if i try to cover these tests using DotCover, one of the projects fails 201 tests that normally pass.

The error is that it tries to load some files from the wrong path, when run through DotCover. I have disabled all sorts of deployment, but resharper still outputs some testfiles to the folder `C:\project\Src\TestResults`, but these are removed once the tests have completed. When run through dotcover the following path generates the error:

`C:\project\Src\project.Test4\bin\Debug\Deploy_abc 2014-07-01 13_26_56\Out\Configuration\Configuration.xml`

The file it trying to find is located this folder:

`C:\project\Src\project.Test4\bin\Debug\Configuration\Configuration.xml`

So it seems that DotCover does not adopt the settings from resharper, or that there is some setting in the `project.Test4.csproj`-file which specifies this path. I have been through the csproj-file but didn't find anything, which is why i now turn to you guys.

As a bonus i can inform you that DotCover pass the tests if i run them individually, which only confuses me further.

Please advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to specify path to .testsettings file? On the 'MsTest' page, click 'Use this Test Run Configuration', and then choose a .testsettings file (dotCover | Options).

Comment: When asking for further clarification, this should probably go in the comments.